# LS Command output to file

Tags: files, output

I want to capture to a file the output of the ls command

```
ls >> lsOutput.log
```

This one works if executed in the command line. But when put inside a shell script (`lsOutput.sh`), returns

```
./lsOutput.sh: 3: ./lsOutput.sh: total: not found
```

`lsOutput.sh` code

```
#!/bin/sh

`ls -lrt` >> lsOutput.log
```

Comment: The backticks around the command in the script make it mean something *very* different than the plain command run from the command line.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just remove the backticks from your script:

```
#!/bin/sh

ls -lrt >> lsOutput.log
```

Otherwise, the command is executed, and then its output is substituted and executed.

For example:

```
echo date
```

will output: `date`, while

```
`echo date`
```

will output current date, i.e. it will first evaluate to `date`, and then executed, which is calling the program `date` itself.

Comment: Hi.. Thank you aularon. It worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi auloran, probably you can also help me with this inquiry: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117609/capture-error-of-ls-to-file